# How can I validate my forms or views in Django so that they can only edit the User Model only to those that belong to that data?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have 2 models that I will allow users to edit separately, one is called User(Django default auth) and the other is UserProfile.

models.py (UserProfile)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', default='avatar/default.png')
    header = models.ImageField(upload_to='header', default='header/default.png')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class UserUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    """
    This view is for editing only the User model. /edit/
    """
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'user/user_edit.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) mixin so that only logged-in users can access the view.

Then, override the `get_object` method, and return the model instance you want to edit.

You don't need the username in the URL any more, so you can remove `slug_field = 'username'`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'user/user_edit.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

If you have a similar view for editing the user profile you would return `self.request.user.userprofile` instead.

Comment: But i have a problem, i have this user "cotizcesar" and this URL (http://.../u/cotizcesar/edit/).

When a visit another user (http://.../u/oboro/edit/) how i can redirect the user to its own URL?

Comment: My suggestion is you remove the username from the url completely and use `/u/edit/` instead. If you want to check the username and redirect, you could override the dispatch method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will give you the point for the answer, very good and short. But I think when I have a username with the name edit for example it will create conflicts.

Example: https://plxapp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: It can be a good idea to [disallow certain usernames](https://github.com/NicoJuicy/Disallowed-usernames). If you really want to allow a user called `edit`, you can change the url for the editing page e.g.
 `/u-edit/`.

Comment: Thx, i already solved the problem. with:
/u/ = users
/o/ for options (Edit Basic Data, Edit Extra data)